# Trigger event not happening in Firefox and Safari

Tags: php, jquery, eventtrigger

I have an issue where my trigger event is not happening in Firefox and Safari but works in Chrome.

The trigger event is called here:

```
<script>    
function capture() {
    //console.log("function is running");
    jQuery('#square').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var url;
            url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            jQuery('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

            jQuery("#buttonSubmit").trigger( "click" );
        }    
    });
}
</script>
```

It's triggered from a button in a form:

```
<form name="addpro" style="float:right;" method="post">
            <input id="textInput" name="textInput" type="hidden" value="Vælg tekst, farve mv. under skiltet">
            <input id="text2Input" name="text2Input" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="størrelseInput" name="størrelseInput" type="hidden" value="155x60">
            <input id="formInput" name="formInput" type="hidden" value="Firkant">
            <input id="farveInput" name="farveInput" type="hidden" value="Sort">
            <input id="typeInput" name="typeInput" type="hidden" value="Messing Standard">
            <input id="fastgøringInput" name="fastgøringInput" type="hidden" value="Skruer">
            <input id="fontInput" name="fontInput" type="hidden" value="Arial">
            <input id="fontSizeLine1Input" name="fontSizeLine1Input" type="hidden" value="6">
            <input id="fontSizeLine2Input" name="fontSizeLine2Input" type="hidden" value="6">
            <input id="priceInput" name="priceInput" type="hidden" value="470">
            <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="tape.png" />
            <button onclick="capture();" class="buttonSign" value="Læg i kurven" />Læg i kurven</button>
            <input class="buttonSign hidden" id="buttonSubmit" type="submit" name="addcustomcarts" value="Læg i kurven" />           
</form>
```

As you can see I want to run the function capture(); before submitting the form! This works in chrome but not in firefox and safari - what's wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried just `jQuery("#buttonSubmit").click();`? or `jQuery("form[name='addpro']").submit();`?

Comment: Gives same result, works in Chrome but not in Firefox. The site is here - add to cart , is called "Læg i kurven" - bottom right: http://flex-skilte.dk/skiltedesigner/

Comment: Which JQuery version are you using? Is there a PHP elements to this that is not shown?

Comment: jquery.js?ver=1.11.3 - There is a php function that is run afterwards, - called on this trigger. Else is the value by default set as you can se here og by jQuery.

Comment: Tested in FireFox 42: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/673q4dmm/ Works.

Comment: Tested in Safari 5.1.7 (for Windows) with the same code and it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95261/discussion-between-troels-johannesen-and-twisty).

Answer (score 0):

I was initially unable to replicate the issue via JSFiddle. I had to adjust a few things. With the following **HTML**:

```
<div id="square">
</div>
<form name="addpro" style="float:right;" method="post">
    <input id="textInput" name="textInput" type="hidden" value="Vælg tekst, farve mv. under skiltet" />
    <input id="text2Input" name="text2Input" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input id="størrelseInput" name="størrelseInput" type="hidden" value="155x60" />
    <input id="formInput" name="formInput" type="hidden" value="Firkant" />
    <input id="farveInput" name="farveInput" type="hidden" value="Sort" />
    <input id="typeInput" name="typeInput" type="hidden" value="Messing Standard" />
    <input id="fastgøringInput" name="fastgøringInput" type="hidden" value="Skruer" />
    <input id="fontInput" name="fontInput" type="hidden" value="Arial" />
    <input id="fontSizeLine1Input" name="fontSizeLine1Input" type="hidden" value="6" />
    <input id="fontSizeLine2Input" name="fontSizeLine2Input" type="hidden" value="6" />
    <input id="priceInput" name="priceInput" type="hidden" value="470" />
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="tape.png" />
    <button id="buttonCart" class="buttonSign" value="Læg i kurven" />Læg i kurven</button>
    <input class="buttonSign hidden" id="buttonSubmit" type="submit" name="addcustomcarts" value="Læg i kurven" />
</form>
```

I could execute the following **JQuery**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("form[name='addpro']").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Form Submitted");
    });
    jQuery("#buttonCart").click(function(){
        html2canvas(jQuery("#square"),{
            onrendered: function(canvas){
                var imgVal = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                jQuery("#img_val").val(imgVal);
                console.log("Image rendered: " + imgVal);
            },
            logging: true
        });
        jQuery("#buttonSubmit").click();
    });
});
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/673q4dmm/10/

This includes the [html2canvas v0.4.0](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and does seem to work, yet submits the form twice. This might be an issue with the way this plugin works. I have yet to found a work around.